# Test Hadoop HDFS in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm Hadoop newbie.

My hadoop version is 2.8.1 and i uses a eclipse Oxygen 3a.
I'm trying to test Hadoop HDFS Library in Java. Is it possible **can i directly connect to HDFS using the FileSystem library on Java Eclipse**? Namely i want to **do testing hdfs library in Java Eclipse**, not on the cmd.

Here is my source code. This source is working on hadoop distributed environment. However, when i tests in single mode, It doesn't work.

```
package us.qi.hdfs;

import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

public class HDFS_Test{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        String uri = "hdfs://mycluster:9000";
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        conf.set("fs.defaultFS", uri);
        conf.addResource(new Path("/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.8.1/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml"));
        conf.addResource(new Path("/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.8.1/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml"));

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);

        Path[] paths = new Path[args.length];
        for (int i = 0;i < paths.length; i++) {
            paths[i] = new Path(args[i]);
        }

        FileStatus[] status = fs.listStatus(paths);
        Path[] listPaths = FileUtil.stat2Paths(status);
        for (Path p : listPaths) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, Invoking **Configuration Object** in Java results in the following error:

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /datanode-metrics.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:672)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:262)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1025)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:844)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:185)
    at us.qi.hdfs.HDFS_Test.main(HDFS_Test.java:16)
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /namenode-metrics.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:133)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.setFile(RollingFileAppender.java:207)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCatsAndRenderers(PropertyConfigurator.java:672)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:516)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:526)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:127)
    at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:104)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:262)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1025)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:844)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:185)
    at us.qi.hdfs.HDFS_Test.main(HDFS_Test.java:16)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/map/UnmodifiableMap
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration$DeprecationContext.<init>(Configuration.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.<clinit>(Configuration.java:456)
    at us.qi.hdfs.HDFS_Test.main(HDFS_Test.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.map.UnmodifiableMap
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 3 more
```

If someone knows the solution, Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: as far as I know, there is hadoop plug-in for eclipse where you may specify your HDFS and compile/run the jobs you've developed

Comment: When i tests that on another server, It works for me. Maybe That hadoop cluster setting  is wrong.

Comment: all of your cluster nodes should have a passwordless ssh access. you seem to have a permission error, try to re-check the accessibility of your namenode and datanode(s)

Comment: How are you adding the Hadoop libraries into Eclipse? What version did you add? And edit the question to include `us.qi.hdfs.HDFS_Test` class

Comment: @mangusta I already deleted ssh password. And i tests on the hadoop single node.

Comment: @cricket_007 I uses a hadoop 2.8.1.I used the hadoop library by adding libraries in the hadoop shared directory in Eclipse.

Comment: I don't know what "shared directory in Eclipse" means, but I really suggest you use Maven because Hadoop has many many dependencies that it needs

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks! It works!

Comment: Cool. Feel free to post your own solution below as an answer so that others may find it useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by rearranging a hadoop library.

I missed some library in eclipse. So i uses a maven for Hadoop-Common, Hadoop-HDFS and it works.